# Creating "checksum" for string in a Firebird/SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, firebird

I need to compare two columns declared as string in 2 different databases, all values of the columns, like 10000 rows at once.
One database is Firebird, and one is SQLite. I want to create some sort of checksum of two columns to see if there are exactly the same values in the two columns.

For integer, I can make a `sum(column)` and if the sum match from the tables, I can assume that it has the same values. This is not bulletproof, but if there are many records, the accuracy increases.
For numerical the same can be used. However, I cannot know how to make similar things to a string column.

Comment: I suggest you use a hash such as MD5 or SHA and then compare the hash. The chances that the detection is wrong is very small with such hashes. Much much less that a checksum.

Comment: One possibility is to fetch all the string values in Delphi (make sure you specify an `ORDER BY` clause for consistent results) and compute a MD5. You can use [THashMD5](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Hash.THashMD5) for that. Call [`Update()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Hash.THashMD5.Update) on every value.

Comment: One option If you have the space would be to load the data from one database into a staging/temp table in the other and then use an EXCEPT query between the two tables to see if any rows differ.

Comment: @Brian If table 1 contains `A`, `A`, `B` and table 2 contains `A`, `B`, `B`, then your `EXCEPT` query won't detect anything.

Comment: One side note on your Integer detection - accuracy highly depends on your data - if your integer data has similar values and in each row it can change up and down with same delta - probability of giving you false equality will not be very low.

Comment: @Miroslav. Indeed. However is only a fast check to detect the "not correct" situation.

Answer (score 1):

I see several possibilities.

**1. Per row comparison**

The easiest is to check the values one row per one row from Delphi code. It has the huge benefit of finding immediately which data row is not synchronized.

But if has the drawback of reading the whole data from the DB.

**2. Hash in SQL SELECT**

If you want to do the check in-place, with no data retrieval, then you need to compute the hash of the columns.

Firebird 4 has cryptographic hash functions like MD5 or SHA1, and you [may be able to find a suitable UDF library](https://web.archive.org/web/20231130110334/https://www.ibphoenix.com/download/tools/udf) for older Firebird revisions.  They are easy to implement with SQLite3, as a [custom aggregate function](https://sqlite.org/appfunc.html).

Ensure you hash the UTF-8 text version of the columns, because binary/raw storage content is not compatible with the two DBs.

Then you could compute the hash of a column in two SELECT SQL statements.

**3. Iterative approach**

If the data is INSERTed into the DB, not UPDATEd, then you could add a "hash" field in each row. When a row is INSERTed, you retrieve the last hash (which may be cached in memory for efficiency), then you hash the new appended values.

Then you can easily compare the resulting hash of the last row, and check if data are the same on both DB.

An alternative may be to compute this hash in memory, not as field in the DB. It will only retrieve the data once at startup, then refresh it when something is INSERTed. It may be enough to check if two DBs are in sync.